# AWK : Unzipping and printing File Name and first line

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I am trying to unzip files in folder and print first line LASTMODIFIEDDATE

But the below will print First line with '-'

```
for file in /export/home/xxxxxx/New_folder/*.gz;
do
gzip -dc "$file" |  awk 'NR=1 {print $0, FILENAME}' |  awk '/LASTMODIFIEDDATE/'
done
```

1.How can i modify the above code to print filename that is unzipped.
2.I am a beginner and suggestion to improve the above code are welcome

Comment: You probably mean `NR==1` to print only the first line (in which case you probably also want an `exit` in the rule to not process the rest of the file and you can combine that with the `&& /LASTMODIFIEDDATE/` pattern match to do this in one awk instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

Your first `awk` should have double equals signs if you mean to address the first line:

```
awk 'NR==1{...}'
```

Your second `awk` will only ever see the output of the first `awk`, which only shows the first line, so you will not see any lines with LASTMODIFIED in them unless they are the first. So this will show you the first line and any lines containing LASTMODIFIED.

```
for ...
do
   echo $file
   gzip -dc  "$file" | awk 'NR==1 || /LASTMODIFIED/'
done
```

Or you may mean this:

```
for ...
do
   gzip -dc  "$file" | awk -v file="$file" 'NR==1{print $0 " " file} /LASTMODIFIED/'
done
```

which will print the first line followed by the filename and also any lines containing LASTMODIFIED.

Answer (score 0):

Do this with an echo. Also you might want to use grep instead of awk in this case.

```
for file in /export/home/xxxxxx/New_folder/*.gz;
do
    echo $file
    gzip -dc "$file" | grep LASTMODIFIEDDATE
done
```

Comment: You probably want `awk -vfile=$file` and `{print $0, file}` instead of using `FILENAME` at this point.